# Compare two different date formats in a query

Tags: asp.net, datetime, timestamp, ravendb

I have to compare a user entered date, "Dt" (in mm/dd/yyyy format)  with the date in RavenDB - "ReleaseDate"  (time stamp like "/Date(1187668800000)/"). For this I am using the following code which almost gets the job done, but I need little help to finalize loose ends...

How can I compare the two dates so I can get the query to run successfully.

```
    public ActionResult Calculation(DateTime? Dt)
    {             
        var store = new DocumentStore { Url = "http://localhost:80" };
        store.Initialize();

        var CalcModel = new CalcViewModel();

        using (var session = store.OpenSession())
        {       
         //Converting user entered date dt in mm/dd/yyyy format to total 
         //milliseconds - So that later I can compare this value to RavenDB
         //time stamp date format (older versions)

          DateTime d1 = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1);
          DateTime d2 = Dt.Value.ToUniversalTime();
          TimeSpan ts = new TimeSpan(d2.Ticks - d1.Ticks);

          double tmillisecs = ts.TotalMilliseconds; //Not yet using this value. 

          CalcModel.MoviesByDate = session.Query<Movies>()
                                   .Where(x => x.ReleaseDate.Ticks == ts.Ticks)            
                                   .Count();

          // this is where I need to compare two dates - ts.ticks gives the
          // required value of date (1187668800000) multiplied by 10000.
        }

        return View(CalcModel);

    }
```

Right now, when I debug I know what value ts.ticks is showing... and its like I said above in the code comments, the required value multiplied by 10000. But I have no clue at run time , what the value in x.ReleaseDate is or x.ReleaseDate.Ticks is.. am I doing this correctly. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Umm... I think you seriously misunderstand how SQL dates work, and how it applies to .NET.  The whole point about dates is that they're stored in a numeric format, not a text one.  So when you have a DateTime object, it's not stored as the text date, it's stored as a numeric type that you can convert to any format you want.

Because the .net provider converts database native datetime objects to DateTime objects, you can just compare them natively.  ie:

```
DateTime d1 = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1);
CalcModel.MoviesByDate = session.Query<Movies>()
                               .Where(x => x.ReleaseDates.Date == d1.Date)
                               .Count();
```

Regardless of how RavenDB stores the dates internally, when the DateTime object is materialized in the query, it will be in native .NET format.

Comment: You meant  .Where(x => x.ReleaseDates.Date == d2.Date) and not d1.Date? right? I did not have much luck with this.. let me try once again. Thank you.

Comment: @ZVenue - A date is a date, it doesn't matter what the time is.. Unless you are comparing times as well, in which case leave the .Date part off and use Universal time (assuming you entered the datetimes in universal time)

Comment: Yes.. this worked. Thank you. is the line of code DateTime d2 = Dt.Value.ToUniversalTime(); important to do this.. or can I just use Dt (the parameter value) directly in the query?  like .Where(x => x.ReleaseDates.Date == dt.Date)

Comment: @ZVenue - No, you don't need that line.  But you should change it to `Dt.Value.Date` if you are only comparing dates.  You also have a potential Null reference exception if Dt is null, so you need to do some error checking for that, or supply a default value if null.  Or alternatively, if the value can't be null, change the method to take a normal DateTime.

Comment: Great. Thank you. I already have the null check in place. This works.

Comment: When I am using  .Where(x => x.ReleaseDates.Date == d1.Date) I am getting error because ReleaseDate is of type DateTime? in the model. How can I get around this. I tried using x.ReleaseDates.Value.Date == d1.Date but thats not working.

Comment: @ZVenue - that depends on your data model.  ReleaseDate is nullable.  Is it actually possible to have null release dates?  If not, then change your data model to make ReleaseDate non-nullable.  If they can be nullable, and you only want to query release dates that are non null, then change your query to include a non-null check such as `x.ReleaseDates != null && x.ReleaseDates.Value.Date == d1.Date`

Comment: @MystereMan - no, you don't need this non-null check in your query. RavenDB will do this for you. Further your answer is not really correct since there are not .NET DateTime object that will be compared. Instead RavenDB will analyze the LINQ expression tree and construct a lucene-query out of it. Then, on the server-side a dynamic index will be created and persisted with lucene. The query will then be executed on this index. No native DateTime types here. Your solution works though.

Comment: @DanielLang - You appear to have missed the part where you're comparing only date, and to do that you have to dererence the .Date member of the DateTime object, which is why you need to do the null check.  Regardless of how RavenDB works under the covers, you work with .NET DateTime objects in your .NET code, so my answer is correct.

Comment: @MystereMan - no, even though it looks like if you were working with .NET DateTime objects here you actually don't. Sure, if it was a nullable DateTime type you would normally need to have this NullReference-check, but in that case it's a LINQ expression that doesn't get evaluated, since ravens LINQ-provider only parses the expression tree. The check will make no difference in that case.

Comment: @DanielLang - Your description makes no sense.  Even if what you say is true, the date still has to be dererenced to translate the variable contents.  I understand your point, but the data still has to be copied into the expression tree by C#, and that's where the null reference exception would occur.

Comment: @MystereMan Ah, now I think I'll get what you meant. You were talking about the right side of the comparison, that means the part that doesn't get in as parameter to the lambda-expression, right? In that case you're right - the object will be referenced to copy the actual value into the expression tree. However, in your code sample above, you make a null check for "x", the parameter in the lambda. This lambda is kind of a anonymous function that never gets executed, it only gets analyzed.

Comment: @DanielLang - my null check in the database side of the expression was not for exception purposes, but for selection purposes.  I said "If they can be nullable, and you only want to query release dates that are non null", which means it's using the not null as a where condition to reduce the number of records searched.  Granted, in that specific situation just comparing date would be enough, but in many kinds of expressions you want to reduce record count to improve performance.